# Server name not displayed in visual studio server explorer

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, server-explorer, server-name

Any ideea why my local sever is not displaed in the drop down list where u select the server name?

[image]
Thx!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe your Sql Server Browser service stopped.

Here is the solution.

1. Open the Run dialog (WinKey + R)
2. Type: "services.msc"
3. Select SQL Server Browser
4. Click Properties
5. Change "disabled" to either "Manual" or "Automatic"
6. When the "Start" service button gets enable, click on it.

Done. Now you can select server name from server name drop down list.